# trying to create dynamic subdags from parent dag based on array of filenames

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to move s3 files from a "non-deleting" bucket (meaning I can't delete the files) to GCS using airflow.  I cannot be guaranteed that new files will be there everyday, but I must check for new files everyday.

my problem is the dynamic creation of subdags.  If there ARE files, I need subdags.  If there are NOT files, I don't need subdags.  My problem is the upstream/downstream settings.  In my code, it does detect files, but does not kick off the subdags as they are supposed to.  I'm missing something.

here's my code:

```
from airflow import models
from  airflow.utils.helpers import chain
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.s3_to_gcs_operator import S3ToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.utils import dates
from airflow.models import Variable
import logging

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': dates.days_ago(1),
    'email': ['sinistersparrow1701@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
}

bucket = 'mybucket'
prefix = 'myprefix/'
LastBDEXDate = int(Variable.get("last_publish_date"))
maxdate = LastBDEXDate
files = []

parent_dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='My_Ingestion',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=False
)

def Check_For_Files(**kwargs):
    s3 = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='S3_BOX')
    s3.get_conn()
    bucket = bucket
    LastBDEXDate = int(Variable.get("last_publish_date"))
    maxdate = LastBDEXDate
    files = s3.list_keys(bucket_name=bucket, prefix='myprefix/file')
    for file in files:
        print(file)
        print(file.split("_")[-2])
        print(file.split("_")[-2][-8:])  ##proves I can see a date in the file name is ok.
        maxdate = maxdate if maxdate > int(file.split("_")[-2][-8:]) else int(file.split("_")[-2][-8:])
    if maxdate > LastBDEXDate:
        return 'Start_Process'
    return 'finished'

def create_subdag(dag_parent, dag_id_child_prefix, file_name):
    # dag params
    dag_id_child = '%s.%s' % (dag_parent.dag_id, dag_id_child_prefix)

    # dag
    subdag = models.DAG(dag_id=dag_id_child,
              default_args=args,
              schedule_interval=None)

    # operators
    s3_to_gcs_op = S3ToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id=dag_id_child,
        bucket=bucket,
        prefix=file_name,
        dest_gcs_conn_id='GCP_Account',
        dest_gcs='gs://my_files/To_Process/',
        replace=False,
        gzip=True,
        dag=subdag)


    return subdag

def create_subdag_operator(dag_parent, filename, index):
    tid_subdag = 'file_{}'.format(index)
    subdag = create_subdag(dag_parent, tid_subdag, filename)
    sd_op = SubDagOperator(task_id=tid_subdag, dag=dag_parent, subdag=subdag)
    return sd_op

def create_subdag_operators(dag_parent, file_list):
    subdags = [create_subdag_operator(dag_parent, file, file_list.index(file)) for file in file_list]
    # chain subdag-operators together
    chain(*subdags)
    return subdags

check_for_files = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='Check_for_s3_Files',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=Check_For_Files,
    dag=parent_dag
)

finished = DummyOperator(
    task_id='finished',
    dag=parent_dag
)

decision_to_continue = DummyOperator(
    task_id='Start_Process',
    dag=parent_dag
)

if len(files) > 0:
    subdag_ops = create_subdag_operators(parent_dag, files)
    check_for_files >> decision_to_continue >> subdag_ops[0] >> subdag_ops[-1] >> finished


check_for_files >> finished
```

Comment: What kind of job runs at the backend of these DAGS are these `spark` jobs or some `python` script and what are you using to run it like `livy` or some other method

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.  can you please restate?

Comment: I mean you are only using simple python scripts and not using any spark job right?

Comment: Yes.  simple operators that are default in airflow.  I want to add existing operators at a dynamic rate based on flagged files in S3 I want to ingest into GCS.

Comment: Why is `files` an empty list?

Comment: it can be.  if there are files that meet the requirements, it gets added to the files list.  If there are not any files that meet the requirements, the list is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the recommended way to create a dynamic DAG or sub-DAG in airflow, though there are other ways also, but I guess this would be largely applicable to your problem.

First, create a file `(yaml/csv)` which includes the list of all `s3` files and locations, in your case you have written a function to store them in list, I would say store them in a separate `yaml` file and load it at run time in airflow env and then create DAGs.

Below is a sample `yaml` file:
`dynamicDagConfigFile.yaml`

```
job: dynamic-dag
bucket_name: 'bucket-name'
prefix: 'bucket-prefix'
S3Files:
    - File1: 'S3Loc1'
    - File2: 'S3Loc2'
    - File3: 'S3Loc3'
```

You can modify your `Check_For_Files` function to store them in a `yaml` file.

Now we can move on to dynamic dag creation:

First define two tasks using dummy operators, i.e.the start and the end task. Such tasks are the ones in which we are going to build upon our `DAG` by dynamically creating tasks between them:

```
start = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start',
    dag=dag
)

end = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end',
    dag=dag)
```

Dynamic DAG:
We will use `PythonOperators` in airflow. The function should receive as arguments the task id; a python function to be executed, i.e., the python_callable for the Python operator; and a set of args to be used during the execution.

Include an argument the `task id`. So, we can exchange data among tasks generated in dynamic way, e.g., via `XCOM`.

You can specify your operation function within this dynamic dag like `s3_to_gcs_op`.

```
def createDynamicDAG(task_id, callableFunction, args):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id = task_id,
        provide_context=True,
        #Eval is used since the callableFunction var is of type string
        #while the python_callable argument for PythonOperators only receives objects of type callable not strings.
        python_callable = eval(callableFunction),
        op_kwargs = args,
        xcom_push = True,
        dag = dag,
    )
    return task
```

Finally based on the location present in the yaml file you can create dynamic dags, first read the `yaml` file as below and create dynamic dag:

```
with open('/usr/local/airflow/dags/config_files/dynamicDagConfigFile.yaml') as f:
    # use safe_load instead to load the YAML file
    configFile = yaml.safe_load(f)

    #Extract file list
    S3Files = configFile['S3Files']

    #In this loop tasks are created for each table defined in the YAML file
    for S3File in S3Files:
        for S3File, fieldName in S3File.items():

            #Remember task id is provided in order to exchange data among tasks generated in dynamic way.
            get_s3_files = createDynamicDAG('{}-getS3Data'.format(S3File), 
                                            'getS3Data', 
                                            {}) #your configs here.

            #Second step is upload S3 to GCS
            upload_s3_toGCS = createDynamicDAG('{}-uploadDataS3ToGCS'.format(S3File), 'uploadDataS3ToGCS', {'previous_task_id':'{}-'})

#write your configs again here like S3 bucket name prefix extra or read from yaml file, and other GCS config.
```

Final DAG definition:

The idea is that

```
#once tasks are generated they should linked with the
#dummy operators generated in the start and end tasks. 
start >> get_s3_files
get_s3_files >> upload_s3_toGCS
upload_s3_toGCS >> end
```

Full airflow code in order:

```
import yaml
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

start = DummyOperator(
    task_id='start',
    dag=dag
)


def createDynamicDAG(task_id, callableFunction, args):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id = task_id,
        provide_context=True,
        #Eval is used since the callableFunction var is of type string
        #while the python_callable argument for PythonOperators only receives objects of type callable not strings.
        python_callable = eval(callableFunction),
        op_kwargs = args,
        xcom_push = True,
        dag = dag,
    )
    return task


end = DummyOperator(
    task_id='end',
    dag=dag)



with open('/usr/local/airflow/dags/config_files/dynamicDagConfigFile.yaml') as f:
    configFile = yaml.safe_load(f)

    #Extract file list
    S3Files = configFile['S3Files']

    #In this loop tasks are created for each table defined in the YAML file
    for S3File in S3Files:
        for S3File, fieldName in S3File.items():

            #Remember task id is provided in order to exchange data among tasks generated in dynamic way.
            get_s3_files = createDynamicDAG('{}-getS3Data'.format(S3File), 
                                            'getS3Data', 
                                            {}) #your configs here.

            #Second step is upload S3 to GCS
            upload_s3_toGCS = createDynamicDAG('{}-uploadDataS3ToGCS'.format(S3File), 'uploadDataS3ToGCS', {'previous_task_id':'{}-'})

#write your configs again here like S3 bucket name prefix extra or read from yaml file, and other GCS config.


start >> get_s3_files
get_s3_files >> upload_s3_toGCS
upload_s3_toGCS >> end
```

Comment: Thank you SO much.  so one of the problems i've had was what happens if there's no new files?  one of the problems i face, is that there will always be files in this place, but not guaranteed NEW files to pull, which means the section `upload_s3_toGCS` will not exist, and error out in airflow.

Comment: You can solve the problem by removing the files from the `yaml` file once all these files are uploaded to GCS, in this way only new files will be present in the `yaml` file. And in case there are no new files the `yaml` file will be empty and no dynamic dag will be created. This is why `yaml` file is much better option as compared to storing files in a list.

Comment: The `yaml` file will also help in maintaining logging of the s3 files in a way, if suppose some of the s3 file fail to be uploaded to GCS, then you can also maintain a flag corresponding to that file and then retry these at next DAG run.

Comment: And if there are no new files you can put an `if` condition before the DAG which will check for new files in `yaml` files if there are new files execute it otherwise skip it.

Comment: the problem here is that the downstreams are set.  if the downstreams are set without the actual jobs (because no files exist), it'll error.